# How to delete a column from the history subpanel

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm running the last version of SugarCRM and in the Account view, I'd like to delete the creation date and the modified date from the subpanel History.

I found several posts saying you have to duplicate the ForHistory.php files from the module folder to the

```
/custom/modules/<name_of_module>/subpanels/
```

directory. Then you modify the files so that every ForHistory.php files so that they must have the same number of columns since the history subpanel is a mix of these files.

So I commented every line I didn't want to appear, repaired the SugarCRM solution and the only thing that was deleted was the columns titles.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why would you want to remove the date created column? If it wasn't there, how would you sort what was the most / least recent?

Comment: We are only working with due dates, not creation date nor modification date.